# How should I calculate $\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^\infty\exp\left\{-\frac{1}{2}(x-it)^2\right\}dx$?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, contour-integration

I've read that the residue theorem would help to calculate $$I:=\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^\infty\underbrace{\exp\left\{-\frac{1}{2}(x-it)^2\right\}}_{=:f(x)}dx$$ Since $f$ is an entire function $\oint_\gamma f=0$ for every closed path $\gamma$ (Cauchy's integral theorem would also yield this information).

So, of course, we can consider the composition $\gamma$ of two paths $\gamma_1(s):=s$, $s\in[-R,R]$, and $\gamma_2(s):=Re^{is}$, $s\in[0,2\pi]$, for some $R>0$. It holds $$0=\oint_\gamma f(z)dz=\int_{-R}^Rf(s)\;ds+iR\int_0^{2\pi}\exp\left\{-\frac{1}{2}(Re^{is}-it)^2+is\right\}ds$$
If we could calculate the second integral, we could calculate $I$. However, it doesn't seem to be helpful to consider that integral instead of the original one.

So, do I miss anything? What's the easiest way to obtain $I$?

Comment: Your integral is $\sqrt{2\pi}$ for all $t\in$ **C**.

Comment: @Lucian Yes, I know the result, but I don't know how to obtain it (from the residue theorem).

Comment: For $it\in$ **R**, with the help of the simple linear substitution, the expression becomes a multiple of the [Gaussian integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the rectangular path with vertices at $-R,\, R,\, R+it,\, -R+it$. When $R\to \infty$, the integrals over the vertical sides tend to $0$ by the standard estimate, and you are left with

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp \left\{-\frac{1}{2}(x-it)^2\right\}\,dx = \int_{-\infty +it}^{\infty +it} \exp \left\{-\frac{1}{2}(z-it)^2\right\}\,dz,$$

where the latter integral is straightforwardly an integral well-known from real analysis.

The idea is to use the Cauchy integral theorem to shift the contour in such a way that the integrand becomes simpler.

Comment: I don't see why I'm left with that integral. My understanding from the standard estimate is: If $\gamma$ is a piecewise smooth path and $f:\gamma^\ast\to\mathbb{C}$ is continuous with $|f|\le M\in (0,\infty]$, then it holds $$\left|\int_\gamma f(z)dz\right|\le M\cdot\underbrace{\int_a^b\left|\gamma'(t)\right|dt}_{=:L(\gamma)}$$ So, how did you parameterize the vertical sides in order to see that the integral over them vanish if $R\to\infty$?

Comment: The vertical sides are parametrised by $z = \pm R + i\tau,\, 0 \leqslant \tau \leqslant t$ (disregarding orientation). Then the length of each vertical side is $\lvert t\rvert$, and since $\operatorname{Re} (\pm R + i\tau)^2 = R^2 -\tau^2 \geqslant R^2 - t^2$ we have $\left\lvert \exp \left(-\frac{1}{2}(\pm R+i\tau)^2\right)\right\rvert \leqslant e^{(t^2-R^2)/2}$, which decays very fast to $0$ as $R\to\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

if $f(x,t) = \exp \left\{-\frac{1}{2}(x-it)^2\right\} $ then 
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial t} = -i \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}
$$
so
$$
\frac{\partial }{\partial t} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f dx =  \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\partial f }{\partial t} dx = -i \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\partial f }{\partial x} dx = \left[-if \right]_{-\infty}^{\infty} =0
$$
so we may set $t=0$ giving a well-known form